# unable to connect to virtualbox machine via ssh

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, windows-8.1, virtualbox

Normally with SSH if you do "telnet localhost 22" you'll get something like this back:

SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1

At that point the client is supposed to send something similar back and then the algorithm negotiation takes place.

So if I do `telnet localhost 22` from my guest machine (Ubuntu) that's exactly what happens. If I do `sudo netstat -lntp` I see this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address       Foreign Address     State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22          0.0.0.0:*           LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::22               :::*                LISTEN
```

So that all looks good to me.

My Virtual Box port forwarding settings are as follows:

[image]

The host is running Windows 8.1.

If I try to connect to localhost:4022 from the host OS - from Windows 8.1 - I do not get the `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1` back that I do when I connect to port 22 via the guest OS. And I don't know why.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is HOST IP for the server? How are you trying to connect?

Comment: Here's how I'm trying to connect: http://pastebin.com/CPXCUS15 As for the HOST IP...  ifconfig says 10.0.2.15 but I'm using virtualbox to attach the virtual network adapter via NAT so I think in-so-far as everything else it's concerned it's 192.168.1.34 I guess..

Comment: Please edit your question describe specifically what happens when you try to connect to localhost port 4022 on the host. Does it hang and timeout? Do you get an error message? What does the error say?

Comment: No error message. I guess it hangs. Per http://pastebin.com/CPXCUS15 I think it'd be most accurate to say that it blocks on the fread() call (it shouldn't).

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that you have the port open in iptables? I am fairly certain that by default most/all ports are blocked.

Here is a quick test.

Check your current iptables settings with:

> sudo iptables -L

I expect you will see it has no current rules, which means it will be denying connections. So as a test to verify it is the iptables, flush the tables to allow all (this is a temporary action just to test):

> sudo iptables -F

Now try your external SSH connection.
If it works, this verifies it was iptables. Restart iptables ('sudo service iptables restart') and then take a look at adding the rule(s) for allowing SSH access. You can get fairly granular with your rules. There are many online resources by individuals that are much better versed in iptables than I that you can find with a quick search to help you add the rules.

Comment: Here's the outut of `sudo iptables -L`: http://pastebin.com/ykP05PUV `sudo iptables -F` did nothing. And it seems to me that since I installed SSH via `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` that that ought to have taken care of the iptables stuff anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your virtual network is configured for NAT.

In the port forwarding rules just leave blank the two address fields.

Test connecting to port 4022 of your host from another machine.